# Window.location.replace Error loading endlessly

Tags: javascript, blogger, window.location

My intention is to redirect mobile devices from the standard mobile main page of blogger to another page made by myself for that purpose.

so I got this code and pasted on the head of the blogger theme template

```
<script>
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {window.location.replace("http://mysite.blogspot.com/page-for-mobile.html?m=1");
}
</script>
```

What it happens is that load endlessly I mean, I don't think that is some connection problem it's more like if starts the load again right before it finishes it.

Answer (score 1):

This is because every time you enter the page the code runs and redirects the page.

I would suggest checking to see if you are already on that page or not.

**UPDATED AGAIN**

```
<script>
  if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) && window.location.href.indexOf('m=1') == -1){
    window.location.replace("http://mysite.blogspot.com/page-for-mobile.html?m=1");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: sorry it keeps happening

Comment: I just changed the code. Sorry I was lazy to double check my own code. It should be working considering the initial URL doesn't include the parameter "m=1" and after the first window.location.replace it will.

Comment: Now it throws this error: "The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference" on the line that contains the "&&" of course and it keeps happening the endless load

Comment: @PabloRojo I updated the code again. I doubled checked it should work.